# Having problems with jQuery script for sliding footer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Ok so I am trying to make a pop up sliding footer using jQuery, I have set up the html and css but I'm having trouble making the jQuery script work.
The script file is /js/slidingfooter.js and it looks like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
var open = false;
$('#footerSlideButton').click(function() {
    if(open === false) {
        $('#footerSlideContent').animate({ height: '300px' });
        $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'bottom left');
        open = true;
    } else {
        $('#footerSlideContent').animate({ height: '0px' });
        $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'top left');
        open = false;
    }
});     
});
```

I tried calling it in the functions.php file like this:

```
function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'slidingfooter',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/slidingfooter.js',
        array('jquery') 
    );
}
```

But all that does is when I refresh the page it displays the code in `functions.php` just shows the written code just above the header.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: can you please upload the full  functions.php

Comment: Is your function inside php tags?

Comment: I asked to upload the funcations.php becoz, my aim was to know what @Fabio asked.....

Comment: I fixed it by just wrapping the jquerry code in script tags and putting it in footer.php. But thank you anyway for the support and replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling a php that returns javascript. Mime types are not relate php documents with javascript, but with html. SO, i can see two solutions here,
1) Wrap your javascript code inside off

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
    var open = false;
    $('#footerSlideButton').click(function() {
        if(open === false) {
            $('#footerSlideContent').animate({ height: '300px' });
            $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'bottom left');
            open = true;
        } else {
            $('#footerSlideContent').animate({ height: '0px' });
            $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'top left');
            open = false;
        }
    });     
    });
</script>
```

or (better way)
2) Insert your javascript code inside the current html document with the way above(1).
You can also trigger it [on a button click](https://api.jquery.com/on/) or [using time](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Comment: I added the jquerry script to the footer.php file and now it works like a charm, thank you very much :D